# Is this a application of coupling?

Tags: probability

Suppose $f(x)$ is monotonically increasing in $x\in \mathbb R$. Let $X,Y$ be two identically distributed random variables and $a>b$ are two positive reals. It is obvious that $E[f(aX)]>E[f(bY)]$.

But how can we prove it rigorously? Do we use a third coupled random variable $Z$, in a different probability space, which is identically distributed to $X,Y$ and then prove   $E[f(aZ)]>E[f(bZ)]$?

Next what if we know $X,Y$ are not just identically distributed but also independent? Then do we still need a third random variable $Z$?

**Edit:**
As per the answer of Did, in this question all random variables are non negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might wish to assume that $X\geqslant0$ almost surely, then note more simply that $aX\geqslant bX$ almost surely, hence $f(aX)\geqslant f(bX)$ almost surely, thus $E(f(aX))\geqslant E(f(bX))$ and you are done since $E(f(bX))=E(f(bY))$.

Independence or dependence of $X$ and $Y$ is offtopic. If $X\lt0$ has positive probability, the assertion is wrong.

Comment: To show $E(f(bX))=E(f(bY))$ do we need coupling?

Comment: No, because expectations depend only on distributions.